# SQL question: how to find rows that share all of the same rows in a composite table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on my SQL project using the Oracle database for class, and I'm asked a question that I see far too often.

You have three tables:

- STUDENT: SNO, SNAME
- CLASS: CNO, CNAME
- ATTENDANCE: SNO, CNO, Grade

The question I keep finding is of a similar type: Find the names of the students that attend in all of the classes that "John" (or anyone else) attends.

John attends three classes, so I have to find the students that also attend those three classes (could be more, but those three must be there). However, I won't always know how many classes John (or whoever) attends, so it can't be hardcoded like that.

```
SELECT jclass.CNO  
FROM attendance jclass  
INNER JOIN student on jclass.SNO = student.SNO  
WHERE student.SNAME = 'John';
```

This gets me the classes that John attends. I tried to add the identifier for the other students:

```
SELECT student.SNAME  
FROM student  
INNER JOIN attendance on student.SNO = attendance.SNO  
INNER JOIN class on attendance.CNO = class.CNO  
WHERE student.SNAME <> 'John' 
  AND class.CNO IN (SELECT jclass.CNO  
                    FROM attendance jclass  
                    INNER JOIN student on jclass.SNO = student.SNO  
                    WHERE student.SNAME = 'John');
```

However, this only gets me the students that appear in **at least** one of John's classes, rather than all of them. I can see *why* it's doing this, but I'm not sure how to fix it. It's the one big struggle I'm having with SQL.

Comment: It would help to know what columns are constrained to `not null` and `unique`. For example, the problem would be much easier if `SNO` is primary key in the first table, `CNO` is primary key in the second table, and `(SNO, CNO)` is composite primary key in the third table. Aside from that: What if more than one student is named "John"? The problem stated in terms of a student first name is nonsensical if that is possible (and it is obviously possible!) The question should be asked in terms of a uniquely identifiable student as input.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are `SNO` and `CNO` primary keys? 2) Can a student attend the same class multiple times?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result in a fiddle so we can test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - assuming `SNO` is primary key in the first table, `CNO` is primary key in the second table, and `(SNO, CNO)` is (composite) primary key in the third table, and that the input student is given by a unique identifier (first name is distinctly NOT a unique identifier, so the problem stated in terms of giving "John" as the input makes no sense). Here I assume the "special" student is identified by `SNO = 1001`; you can make `1001` into a variable, or change it to a subquery that selects a (unique!!) `SNO` based on some other inputs.

I didn't try to make the query as efficient as possible, or use features you most likely haven't seen in your class. Rather, I tried to make it as elementary and as readable as possible.

```
select sno
from   attendance
where  cno in (select cno from attendance where sno = 1001)
group  by sno
having count(*) = (select count(*) from attendance where sno = 1001)
;
```

The strategy is simple: the subquery in the `in` condition finds the classes attended by the "special" student, then from the attendance table we select only rows for those classes. Group by student, and count. Keep only the students for whom the count is equal to the total count for the "special" student. Note the last condition is about groups, not about input rows, so it belongs in the `having` clause.

Comment: It's meant to be a simple project at the moment. The real project is a first letter and last name. 

And yes, the primary and composite keys you mentioned are what I'm using. I just forgot to mention them.

And I did try your version out. It definitely worked. Apologies for not being as clear as I should have been with the states of each column.